# Add item to existing Sharepoint list from excel

Tags: vba, sharepoint, connect, listitem

I have a existing sharepoint list naming (**Emp DB**) which contains below fields

1. EmpID:
2. Emp Name:
3. Supervisor:
4. emailID:
5. Contact:

i want to add items frequently to the above list from excel sheet contains same fields as a columns.  VBA coding is required...

Any help on this is very much appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet view is not a good way to do this. Either you use VBA and macro from excel or access to update the list. The problem I have is the exact same but with lookup columns to filter the form used to add a new object. When the cut and paste is done from excel the list can't figure out which column value to use and connect it to the value from another list. 
I have also heard that you could use web services in SharePoint but i haven't got there yet. Here are some articles that may help you regarding VBA:

https://scottlyerly.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/excel-geeking-using-vba-and-ado-to-change-data-to-sharepoint-lists/

https://flylib.com/books/en/3.464.1.67/1/

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/update-list-from-excel-using-vba

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your list view and excel sheet columns are in the same order. Click the **edit** link inside "new item or edit this list" at the top of your list page. Now your list is in "datasheet view." Highlight the rows from excel that you want to enter and copy them. On your list page, click the leftmost cell of the empty row at the bottom, and do CTR+V. This should prompt you to "Allow Access" to your clipboard and paste your new entries onto the list.

If you have any trouble see [this guide](http://3sharp.com/blog/copy-and-paste-from-excel-to-a-sharepoint-list/).

Comment: thanks for your response , however i dont want to copy paste,it should be done programmatically VBA